# cognos: Pick up the initial value for every row of a crosstab

Tags: cognos

I have a requirement in which i have to pick up the initial value of each row in a crosstab..
My crosstab looks like this

value   1960  1970  2010  2011
aus        10               5          11      6 
eng                             5        2 
bra            11           4
ind                           8             11
i have to add another column which picks up the initial value for every row based on the year..
so the result should look like this.

value   1960  1970  2010  2011    initialValue
aus        10               5          11      6         10
eng                             5        2          5 
bra            11           4                             11
ind                           8             11                    8

Comment: Is your data relational or dimensional?

Comment: Assuming relational data, I think you'll need a second query to identify the "initial" year.  Then you can use that with a third query to get the earliest value for each country (or whatever that is).  Then you can join that to your original query on country.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the minimum() function to determine the lowest value for year and then return the value corresponding to that. The expression for the initialValue data item would be something like:

```
total(
CASE
WHEN [Year] = minimum([Year] for [Language])
THEN [Value]
ELSE 0 
END
for [Language])
```

We get the lowest year for the specific language in the data set using the minimum() function using the *for* clause to define the aggregation level. If the year of the row matches this number, we output the value, otherwise we output 0. We then total everything up for each language which should give us the value for the lowest year.

This solution assumes that the numbers displayed in your crosstab are totals of lower-level row detail. If the aggregate is something different, such as average or count, the wrapping summary function should be changed accordingly.

Comment: it is throwing the following error... "RSV-VAL-0010 fiailed to load the report specification. XQE-PLN-0001 internal error. The query could not be planned by the query service: Index: 0, Size: 0"

Comment: That's a non-specific error. Is it a relational or dimensional source?

Comment: It is a relational source

Comment: What is your database provider?

Comment: I don't think I can troubleshoot your problem remotely. You will have to play with it. The concept is sound but Cognos can be finicky. Since I don't have your database or report I can't test it on my side. Looking at the code again. One thing you might try is taking the 'minimum([Year] for [Language]) reference above and put it in its own data item. Then replace the reference and in the CASE statement and replace it with the new data item name. That might help as Cognos may be having trouble with the aggregate function within the CASE statement.